# failing approach to dispose off the zombie views in backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

so i had the same famous problem of zombie views in my backbone app. I tried this to become a superhero :P

```
var Router=Backbone.Router.extend({
             routes:{
                  "":"loadDashboard",
                  "home":"loadDashboard",
                  'post-leads':"loadPostLeads"
                },
                initialize:function(){
                window.currentView=null;
                },

            loadPostLeads:function(){
            require(['views/post-leads'],function(leads){
            if(window.currentView!=null)
            {window.currentView.remove();}
            window.currentView=new leads();
            window.currentView.render();
            })

        },

              loadDashboard: function(){
        require(['views/dashboard'],function(dashboard){
            if(window.currentView!=null)
            {window.currentView.remove();}
            window.currentView=new dashboard();
            window.currentView.render();
            })
        }
          });
```

This doesn't work. I wanted something simple and don't want to use marionette or anything similar for that sake. Whats going wrong above? Is it a sensible approach?

Comment: I LOLed @superhero :D

Comment: :) any word on this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle what you do should work, but there are some things that Backbone can't clean up, because it doesn't know of them.

First, you should make sure that you are using a  recent version of Backbone (`0.9.9` or newer). There have been some improvements to the event binding code, which makes it easier for the `View.remove` method to do all the necessary cleanup.

The common gotchas are:

**Listening to model events**:

```
//don't use other.on (Backbone doesn't know how to clean up)
this.model.on('event', this.method);

//use this.listenTo (Backbone cleans up events when View.remove is called)
//requires Backbone 0.9.9
this.listenTo(this.model, 'event', this.method);
```

**Listening to DOM events outside your view's scope**:

```
//if you listen to events for nodes that are outside View.el
$(document).on('event', this.method);

//you have to clean them up. A good way is to override the View.remove method
remove: function() {
  $(document).off('event', this.method);
  Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
}
```

**Direct references**:

```
//you may hold a direct reference to the view:
this.childView = otherView;

//or one of its methods
this.callback = otherView.render;

//or as a captured function scope variable:
this.on('event', function() {
  otherView.render();
});
```

**Closures**:

```
//if you create a closure over your view, or any method of your view, 
//someone else may still hold a reference to your view:
method: function(arg) {
  var self = this;
  return function() {
    self.something(x);
  }
}
```

Avoiding the following pitfalls should help your views to get cleaned up correctly.

**Edit based on comment**:

Ah, you didn't mention the full problem in your question. The problem with your approach is, as I gather, is that you're trying to render the two views into the same element:

```
var View1 = Backbone.View.extend({el:"#container" });
var View2 = Backbone.View.extend({el:"#container" });
```

And when you remove `View1`, the `View2` does not correctly render.

Instead of specifying the view `el`, you should render the views **into** an element. On your page you should have a `#container` element, and append the view's element into the container.

```
loadPostLeads: function () {
  var self = this;
  require(['views/post-leads'], function (leads) {
    self.renderView(new leads());
  })
},

loadDashboard: function () {
  var self = this;
  require(['views/dashboard'], function (dashboard) {
    self.renderView(new dashboard());
  })
},

renderView: function(view) {
  if(window.currentView) {
    window.currentView.remove();
  }

  //the view itself does not specify el, so you need to append the view into the DOM
  view.render();
  $("#container").html(view.el);

  window.currentView = view;
}
```

Comment: see, when i execute my code, it removes it. but when i create a new view and do console.log(window.currentView) it shows el as undefined :(

Comment: @beNerd, edited my answer. You really should try to give all that information in your original question.

Comment: You might want `return Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);` in your `remove` to match the default behavior.